# can call fetch but not other Backbone collection methods

Tags: backbone.js

In the app.js file of my Backbone app with a Rails backend, I initiated a collection, and set it as the collection on a jobForm view after the fetch() method completed its retrieval of the records.

```
var app = {

  init: function () {

 this.collections.job  = new this.Collections.job();
 this.collections.job.fetch().complete(function(){
      app.views.jobForm = new app.Views.jobForm({ collection : app.collections.job });

}
```

Inside the jobForm view (which is the view for the user to enter job details), I listen for a submit on the form and then use the collection to create a new job on form submission.

```
events : {
            'submit form' : 'addDoc'
        },
        addDoc : function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            // app.collections.job.create({
            console.log(this.collection);
            this.collection.create({

                job_title : this.$('.job_title').val(),
                position : this.$('.position').val(), 
                company : this.$('.company').val(),

            }, { error : _.bind(this.error, this) });
```

However, I'm getting an error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'create'
```

The code isn't even trying to make a network request because it doesn't think it has the create method. You'll notice that I did a console log of the collection prior to creating it and it returns a collection of jobs (that was created before I added backbone to the app), so it is a collection.

```
child {cid: "c1", attributes: Object, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object, changed: Object…}
_changing: false
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c1"
__proto__: Surrogate
constructor: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
initialize: function () {
model: function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }
url: "/jobs"
__proto__: Object
```

In the console, I instantiated a new collection, called fetch, retrieved some results, and tried some other collection methods on it, such as collection.at(0), and was told that the object doesn't have the method 'at'.

Strangely, this code (the form linked to a collection) is code that I copied from another working Backbone app of mine.

So, if I'm able to call fetch(); on this object after instantiating it, but not call other Backbone Collection methods (such as 'at' and 'create') what is this object that I'm trying to call create on, and what can I do to fix the problem...

Comment: if `this.collection.job` is your actual collection, try `this.collection.job.create`

Comment: I did this.collection.create({... because I was trying to call the create method of the collection that the view was instantiated with (which the view has a reference to)  (which is how i got it to work in my other app), rather than call create on the name of the actual collection (i.e. this.collection.job.create). However, I tried your suggestion and it said, ': Cannot read property 'job' of undefined' . I think the way I had it should be the way it works. You can call method on the collections/models that views are instantiated with by doing this.model.render(); etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I was extending a model

```
app.Collections.job = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

rather than a collection

```
app.Collections.job = Backbone.Collection.extend({
```